# MergedDictionaries in XAML rewritten to code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, mergeddictionaries

Is
this XAML code in **App.xaml**:

```
<Application x:Class="Company.Product.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
    <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Company.Windows.Themes.Theme1;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Company.Windows.Themes.Theme1;component/Themes/Company.Windows.Controls.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Company.Windows.Themes.Theme1;component/Themes/Company.Windows.Controls.Data.xaml"/>               
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

equivalent to:

**App.xaml**:

```
<Application x:Class="Company.Product.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
</Application>
```

and in **App.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {               
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Company.Windows.Themes.Theme1;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Company.Windows.Themes.Theme1;component/Themes/Company.Windows.Controls.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("/Company.Windows.Themes.Theme1;component/Themes/Company.Windows.Controls.Data.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        });
    }
}
```

*One side note:* Do I need to call Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();  in this situation before i start adding the merged dictionaries? I think at this moment the default 
MergedDictionaries collection is initially empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ans1) Yes absolutely. They are same.

Ans2) No you do not need to `Clear()` them for there are no `MergedDictionaries` and hence `Count` is `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you speedy - almost immediate - answer. :)